# How to configure ssl Certificate dropwizard on Localhost

Tags: java, ssl, localhost, okhttp, dropwizard

Using android okHttp requires https connection, otherwise it won't work, spend two days trying to be able to use http instead, but no result, nothing worked for me

```
OkHttpClient            baseClient       = unidentifiedAccess.isPresent() ? connectionHolder.getUnidentifiedClient() : connectionHolder.getClient();
      OkHttpClient            okHttpClient     = baseClient.newBuilder()
              .connectionSpecs(Util.immutableList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT//CLEARTEXT
              ))
                                                           .build();
```

Server is located on my MAC OS.

Server runs simple jar, dropwizard framework.

Running on:
http://asylzat.com:8080/v1/directory/test

And what i am trying to do is to make it **https** instead of **http**: because okHttp don't works other way.

I bought ssl certificate, from **Reg.ru**, they send me two files:

1. www.asylzat.com.key
2. www.asylzat.com.csr

And there is instruction only for their hosting server and apachi.

What am i supposed to do?

This ssl certificate is turned to me a huge, unsolvable problem, i am trying to figure out and solve it nearly four days, trying to learn more about certificates.

[dropwizard ssl](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/core.html)

[generating ssl certificate](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html)

No result, there is a lot of staff, csr, crt, keystore, pk12, jsr it all goes forever, i don't know is it to hard to configure it, as if you have to learn all about it, and kinda be system administrator, but ssl administrator

Anyone who does knows, Please help, I need to be able to run dropwizard jar on https, which is only demo, just because adroid okhttp receives only https. Such a small staff, became a huge problem for me, PLEASE HELP!!!

REG.RU Just send me an email:

```
_globalsign-domain-verification=mcd5zjYtpb7PT...
```

I don't know what to do with it, I asked reg.ru but they answered that *"your hosting server is not from ours, so that we can't help you"*.

In .yml file there is a .keystore or .jrs is used, how are they made?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: too long for a comment*
Working with certificates and the related stuff requires a little bit of learning. Quote from the Jetty's documentation:

> Configuring SSL can be a confusing experience of keys, certificates,
>   protocols and formats, thus it helps to have a reasonable
>   understanding of the basics.

Jetty's documentation tries to be helpful with this: Start from `Understanding Cerificates and keys` http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#understanding-certificates-and-keys
Next check `Requesting a trusted certificate` http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#requesting-trusted-certificate There you will learn how the private certificate key helps you to create a CSR (certificate signing request).
This CSR is processed from your certificate provider to create a certificate (file).
In the `Loading keys and certificates` you will learn the basic steps and commands to process the above files in format suitable for deployment with your Java application. Just read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to start server on self signed certificate?

```
keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA
```

.yml file

```
server:
#  softNofileLimit: 1000
#  hardNofileLimit: 1000
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
    - type: https
      port: 8443
      keyStorePath: example.keystore
      keyStorePassword: example
```

Comment: Yes i did [https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml] as it was in example, but the thing is, it works with untrusted certificate, and also it works with example.keystore which i downloaded from github example, whenever i try to generate my own example.keysore i am receiving an error